# What is the opposite of baseline?

Tags: machine-learning, theory, methodology

I have created a prediction model and on the one hand I have to compare it with other baseline models, and on the other hand, I have to compare it with the ideal approach (supported by additional data), so I would like to know how I can call it (antonym of baseline) in the research paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term is **Oracle**.

Some references:

- [SO question describing the term](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10542937/674487)
- [Scientific articles related to machine learning using the term](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=machine+learning+oracle&btnG=)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure there is such a term, I would just go for:

- Perfect model/predictor
- Optimal model/predictor

Or as you suggested the ideal model. As long as you clearly define what the term means in your paper you can call it either.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I would just like to check if there is a scientific term used which expresses the antonym of the term baseline

Comment: See my answer above :)